# Pivot key value data to row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have data in a table in a 'key-value' pairing format - for each `Id` you can have multiple `key/value` pairing values with additional column specifying Table value.

DataTable:

```
ID    Table  Key     Value
--    --     --      --
221   Tab1   Field2  Jon
221   Tab1   Field5  Snow
221   Tab1   Field4  Male
221   Tab1   Field3  Pass
2256  Tab1   Field2  Jil
2256  Tab1   Field5  Dark
```

Data in `Key` column refers to actual column name refered to by (table)data in Table column.

Now, I want pivot this data such that each `ID` is only represented as a single row in relevant table and data copied to appropriate column:

Tab1:

```
Id   Field1 Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6
--   --     --      --      --      --      --
221         Jon     Pass    Male    Snow
2256        Jil                     Dark
```

How do I go about writing this?

Comment: Considering that you have no row with the value `Field6` but have a column for it, this suggest you have an indeterminate number of values; correct? Have you looked up a dynamic Pivot? There are quite a few examples on Stack Overflow on how to use them. Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: This overall style is called [entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), and can have significant penalties, even (or perhaps especially) when implemented well.  You may want to reevaluate whether you really have such a sparse dataset.

Answer (score 2):

First, sample DDL/DML statements:

```
CREATE TABLE t (ID INT, [Table] VARCHAR(5), [Key] varchar(6), Value varchar(5))
INSERT INTO t VALUES (221, 'Tab1', 'Field2', 'Jon'),
(221 ,'Tab1','Field5','Snow'),
(221 ,'Tab1','Field4','Male'),
(221 ,'Tab1','Field3','Pass'),
(2256,'Tab1','Field2','Jil '),
(2256,'Tab1','Field5','Dark')
```

A static pivot query with hard-coded columns looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t 
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Key] IN ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6]))p
```

Returns:

```
ID      Table   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6
221     Tab1    NULL    Jon     Pass    Male    Snow    NULL
2256    Tab1    NULL    Jil     NULL    NULL    Dark    NULL
```

If you need to dynamically determine the columns from the data, here's an approach using sp_executesql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT p.*
FROM t
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Key] IN (' + 
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Key]) FROM t FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + '))p
'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Returns:

```
ID      Table   Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5
221     Tab1    Jon     Pass    Male    Snow
2256    Tab1    Jil     NULL    NULL    Dark
```

This line:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Key]) FROM t FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

just brackets and delimits the columns into this string:

```
[Field2],[Field3],[Field4],[Field5]
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful in structuring my solution. I incorporated into dynamic sql for implementation. Awesome Max.

Comment: @Sandiyan Great! Can you accept the answer? Thank you.